# Apache Camel MDC UnitOfWork

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, mdc

We are currently using Apache Camel's (within Spring Boot Application) MDC logging functionality to log custom correlation ID. With Camel 2.x we've implemented a custom UnitOfWork which extends MDCUnitOfWork which sets additional MDC properties based on the Exchange provided. Since Camel 3 MDCUnitOfWork's constructor changed from

`public MDCUnitOfWork(Exchange exchange)` to

`public MDCUnitOfWork(Exchange exchange, InflightRepository inflightRepository, String pattern, boolean allowUseOriginalMessage, boolean useBreadcrumb)`

Do you have an idea, where to get all the additional constructor parameters from, when configuring the custom MDCUnitOfWork as a Spring bean?

Answer (score 3):

```
super(exchange, exchange.getContext().getInflightRepository(), "", false, false);
```

Why don't you try this?

Comment: Thanks, that should do the job! Sadly, the whole idea of logging of custom properties is not working well with MDC.

Comment: Maybe @clausIbsen could help you if he sees this question.